# Wordpress - include php in post

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, function

I want to include a php file in my post.
The post content contains a native video player and some text. Like this:

```
[video player]
<p>Some Text</p>
```

I want to include a php file called `content-link.php` between `[video player]` and `<p>Some Text</p>`

I tried to add a function in `functions.php`

```
function replace_content($content)
{
  $search  = array('<p>');
  $arr = get_template_part( 'content-link');
  $replace = array($arr.'<p>');
  $content = str_replace($search, $replace, $content);
  return $content;
}
add_filter('the_content', 'replace_content');
```

but the file is included above `[video player]`

Can anyone to give me an idea?
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do just like this in the file which print out the post:

```
[video player]
get_template_part( 'content', 'link');
<p>Some Text</p>
```

;)

Answer (score 0):

If it is an external php file like how i see it i guess it would be include "../your/path/here.php";

so in your case it would be :

```
  <?php include "../path/functions.php"; ?>     
  [video player]
 <p>Some Text</p>
```

so you include the php from another source now that you've used this you can call your function in your page (if the page also has the .php extension).

Comment: did you copy this exactly ? , then it won't work if you don't get it i think you might first go and learn php ;)

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to create custom page template, in order to include executive PHP code in your page.

In Wordpress system it is not allowed to insert code directly while publishing.

So create this template ([read first how-to](http://codex.wordpress.org/Stepping_Into_Templates)) and insert whatever you want as PHP code, then use this template in your post/page.

Also there are varius plugins, which allow you to run the PHP code, written while publishing, but I personally do not recommend this solution, because it may lead to serious security problems.

Comment: This is not a solution for me. Thank you, anyway!

Answer (score 0):

if you are asking about including the file from the dashboard editor, there is a plugin for this

https://wordpress.org/plugins/php-snippets/